# Breakpoint error during first line of PrepareforSegue

Tags: ios, swift

I have designated a segue from my NewsController class to FullNews Class that worked before i added a prepareforsegue function. After adding it, the segue no longer occurs and freezes as soon as prepareforsegue occurs with a thread breakpoint at the first line. Here are the two classes. The code is below

```
import UIKit

class NewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate {
    var parser: NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser()
    var info: [newsarticle] = []
    var postTitle: String = String()
    var postDesc: String = String()
    var eName: String = String()
    var index: Int = Int()
    /*
     // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
     // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
     override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
     // Drawing code
     }
     */
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://brrsd.k12.nj.us/rss/News.xml")!
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
    }
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qualifiedName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
    {
        eName = elementName
        if elementName == "item" {
            postTitle = String()
            postDesc = String()
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return info.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell
        if let reusedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") {
            cell = reusedCell
        } else {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }

        let news: newsarticle = info[indexPath.row]
        if let label = cell.textLabel {
            label.text = news.title
        }
        return cell    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        let data = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        if (!data.isEmpty) {
            if eName == "title" {
                postTitle += data
            } else if eName == "description" {
                postDesc += data
            }
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName == "item" {
            let newsart: newsarticle = newsarticle()
            newsart.title = postTitle
            newsart.description = postDesc
            info.append(newsart)
        }
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        index = indexPath.row
            performSegueWithIdentifier("NewsTransfer", sender:self)
    }
     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       let Destination: FullNews = segue.destinationViewController as! FullNews
        Destination.info = info[index]
    }




    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}


import UIKit

class FullNews: UIViewController {
    var info: newsarticle = newsarticle()
    @IBOutlet weak var NewsTitle: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet weak var Desc: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       NewsTitle.textLabel?.text = info.title
       Desc.text = info.description
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You are forcing an unwrap of the destination view controller, which more than likely is not available. Check your segue connection in your storyboard to make sure that it is properly connected between your screens.

Comment: I checked and there is a segue connection between my prototype cell and FullNews view. I didn't want to force the unwrap but it wont compile otherwise. Why would the controller not be available?

Comment: Is the class of the destination view controller set to `FullNews`?

Comment: yes it is set to FullNews

Comment: Have you just set a breakpoint in that function?  Check for a blue flag in the margin

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about how the flow of your app is, but perhaps you can use `if` and `if let` to check on the segue before performing `prepareForSegue`

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     if segue.identifier == "NewsTransfer" {

         // additionally, you can print something here to see if this step worked
         //print("segue.identifier is NewsTransfer")

         if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! FullNews {

              //print("destination is FullNews")

              destination.info = info[index]
         }
     }
}
```

Also make sure your segue is properly connected and named

EDIT
Seems like you have created a breakpoint and therefore it stopped at the breakpoint. drag the blue arrow on the left away to delete it and the code would continue to run.

Comment: Actually that's one of the few examples where a forced unwrapping crash is very useful to fix that bug at compile time so it will never happen again at runtime since the controllers are "hard-coded" in Interface Builder. The other way round the segue will never be performed if the check fails.

Comment: I did as you have added but i still get a Thread 1: breakpoint 6.1 at the first if statement. I have double checked and the segue identifier is NewsTransfer. I also get a "Treating a forced downcast to "FullNews" as an optional will never produce nil" error. Looking at the console however i see, Destination(BRGO.FullNews). Im honestly not sure why this isn't  working at this point

Comment: after doing that `if` statements, you can force unwrap. anyway, is the color of the thread 1 breakpoint 6.1 line in green? because now it seems to me that you have created a breakpoint. look to the left, is there a blue arrow pointing to the first `if` statement? if there is, drag it away and it should delete it

Comment: Yes i did have that originally. I restarted Xcode and now when i run it, the if statements work fine, in fact the whole runs twice as i get sets of the print functions. but i am now receiving a thread 1: sigabrt error in the App delegate class

Comment: so perhaps you can remove the changes you just made and see if your previous problem was solved from removing the breakpoints. if it was due to the breakpoints then please accept the answer and if there are other questions, post separately and we will try to help